# http://localhost:8080/h2.console is not working showing as white label error in spring boot frame work

Tags: jpa, jdbc

after starting server, if I tried open database using http://localhost:8080/h2.console is not working it showing the white label error.

I have tried adding

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/portal;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```